# Sentry - unable to request token oauth http error 405

Tags: oauth, sentry

I created an Sentry application under `Settings > Account > API > Applications`.
My web server is running receives the callback requests with the `code` param.
But whenever I send a token request like below I receive HTTP `405` error.

```
    fetch("https://sentry.io/oauth/token", {
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: sentry_client_id,
        client_secret: sentry_secret,
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8000/app/dashboard.html",
        code: code,
      }),
    })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The request to the token endpoint needs to be a URL-encoded form, not JSON encoded. Do like this instead:

```js
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("client_id", clientId);
formData.append("client_secret", clientSecret);
formData.append("code_verifier", codeVerifier);
formData.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
formData.append("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
formData.append("code", code);

var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(formData);

fetch(tokenEndpoint, {
  method: "post",
  body: searchParams,
});
```

The token endpoint may or may not support CORS. I didn't test that in Sentry's case.

Also, I'd use PKCE if Sentry support it. My example above does that with the inclusion of `code_verifier`.